# Differential equation with definite integral. $\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}dx=b$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{f(x)}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}dx=b$$

I want to find the relation between $f(x)$ and $x$, $a$ and $b$ are constants. I don't know if this is a solvable equation, and if it is, I have no idea how to go about solving it.

**edit:** I learned from the comments that there are infinite solutions and restrictions are needed. Actually, $b= \frac c{a(a+d)^2}$ (all are constants), and $f(x)$ needs to be independent of $a$.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions. Is there some restriction on $f$? Consider $f(x)=a^2b$ and $f(x)=|a|bx$ as two.

Comment: Maybe, it's loosely related to the [Abel Transform](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelTransform.html). You can check the link to see whether it's related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As the integral converges and the denominator is of the order $3$,the Taylor series of $f(x)$ around $x=0$ must not have terms greater than degree $1$,(greater than $2$ will give you terms with positive powers, which go to infinity as $x$ goes to infinity, confirming the divergence of those integrals, $x^2$ term will lead to $\ln(x)$ type of term all of which blows up at infinity,)that implies you can consider $f(x)$ to be a linear function and then fit the constants accordingly,
This will give you only some functions as sum of two diverging integrals (coming from higher order terms of the Taylor series) might converge.